# Find the 50th word of all permutations of word AGAIN ,when arranged accord to dictionary

Tags: combinatorics, algebra-precalculus

I have to Find the 50th word of all permutations of word AGAIN ,when arranged accord to dictionary.?There are 60 words with or without meaning ,but how do i find out 50th word .Thanks

*ATTEMPT**

Comment: why this question had been put on hold ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Characters in ascending order=${A,G,I,N}\$

Number of words starting with A $=4!=24$.

Number of words starting with G $=\frac{4!}{2!}=12$.

Number of words starting with I $=\frac{4!}{2!}=12$.

Total numbers up until now=48.

49th word=NAAGI

50th word=NAAIG

Comment: how did you come up with 49th word ?

Comment: 49th number should begin with 'N' as you can see above and since it is the first word with N so it should be lexicographically increasing from the second term as {A,A,G,I} .

Answer (score 3):

**Hints**

1. The problem is slightly complicated because `AGAIN` contains two `A`s.  First solve the problem for the word `ABCDE`.
2. How many permutations of `ABCDE` begin with `A`?  How many begin with `B`?  What letter does the 50th permutation begin with?  Consider  only the permutations that begin with that letter:  how many come before the permutation you are looking for and how many come after?

Comment: Can you please explain in my question about 50 th word .